# PCA: PCA1 vs PC2

Tags: r, pca

I know this question has been asked a million times but I am having trouble with making PCA plots is R.

I have four tables with Eigenvalues from four different populations. I want to compare populations to see which population is most homogenous. I was able to make individual plots for each population but my supervisor want to compare PC1 vs PC2, not just PC1 vs individual number.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Ket me know if you need more information. I have attached the screenshot of one of the tables I have and the corresponding plot I generated to give a better idea. I generated this scatter plots using values given in column one (EV1)

Thanks.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only assume that you have used R's princomp function to calculate the PCs. Try doing this:

```
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- rnorm(100)
z <- rnorm(100)
M <- matrix(c(x,y,z), ncol = 3)
P <- princomp(M)
plot(P$scores[, 1:2]) # plot of princomp1 against princomp2
```

Comment: Hi Russ. Can you please explain your answer? and ya I did use the princomp function

Comment: I think I got it. Let me try this out with my data set

Comment: I'm not sure what there is to explain. The results of princomp get stored in a structure. The 'scores' entry in this structure contains the weightings of your variables against the principle components, so the i'th row and j'th column of 'scores' is the contains the weighting of your i'th variable against the j'th principle component.